# How can I get color from CalendarEvent object on google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I want to get the color(red) below the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr08j.png)

---

I use next code, but I don't know next step.

run main function.

```js
var mainCalendarName = 'main';

function main() {
    var calendar = getCalendar();

    if (calendar == null) {
        return;
    }

    var now = new Date();
    var calendarEventArray = calendar.getEventsForDay(now);

    Logger.log('current color = ' + calendarEventArray[0].getColor()); // not use!!!
    //log 'current color = #FF0000'
}

function getCalendar() {
    var calendarList = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();

    for (i in calendarList) {
        if (mainCalendarName === calendarList[i].getName()) {
            return calendarList[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to enable the Advanced Google Services.

Please see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) description how do that.

Then the following code will do the job

```
function main(){
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list("main", {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
       Logger.log(events.items[i].colorId); //Here the color of the specific event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
So Calendar.Events.list parameter is calendarId and Optional query parameters.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list